# Kann man „zu“ + Verb in Nebensätzen mit „ob ...“ oder „was ...“ benutzen?

Tags: preposition, subordinate-clause, infinitive

Ich weiß, dass man diesen Satz schreiben kann:

> Ich weiß nicht, was ich machen soll.

Aber ist das Folgende richtig/falsch?

> Ich weiß nicht, was *zu machen*?

Ich freue mich sehr auf Ihre Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

> Kann man „zu“ + Verb in Nebensätzen mit „ob …“ oder „was …“ benutzen?

Ja, generell kann man das, und zwar beim sogenannten *Infinitiv mit zu*. Allerdings braucht man dazu normalerweise noch ein weiteres Verb, und das fehlt in Ihrem Beispielsatz.

Richtig wären zum Beispiel die folgenden Sätze, die einen mit *ob* oder *was* eingeleiteten Nebensatz und einen Infinitiv mit *zu* haben:

> - Ich weiß nicht, was *zu machen* **ist**.
> - Ich weiß nicht, ob etwas *zu machen* **ist**.

Mehr zum Thema *Infinitiv mit oder ohne zu* finden Sie unter anderem hier: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/infinitiv

Comment: Warum benutzen Sie ist dort?

Answer (score 0):

Nein, dein zweiter Satz ist kein korrektes Deutsch. Die wörtliche Übersetzung vom Englischen "I don't know what to do" ist dein erster Satz, "Ich weiß nicht, was ich machen soll." Offensichtlicher ist der Zusammenhang zu der längeren Form "I don't know what I should do".